# Error installing AFNetworkActivityLogger with AFNetworking 4.0 - Cocoapods

Tags: github, io, cocoapods, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I get this message after submitting my app to App Store Connect.

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage — Apple will stop accepting
>   submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs When upload myApp

It tells me that my project is using WebView (deprecated library). I found the problem in AFNetworking library, after going to this [page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/4428) they report that version 4.0 this problem was corrected, so when I update my pod and run the pod install I receive the following error.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "AFNetworking/NSURLSession":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    AFNetworking/NSURLSession (= 4.0.1)

  In Podfile:
    AFNetworkActivityLogger (from `https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger.git`, branch `3.0.0`) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      AFNetworking/NSURLSession (~> 3.0)

Specs satisfying the `AFNetworking/NSURLSession (= 4.0.1), AFNetworking/NSURLSession (~> 3.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I really don't understand why or how to fix it, I already checked the AFNetworkActivityLogger Git project since here the cocoapods indicates that problem. On their [page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger/pull/61) they mention that the problem is resolved in an update, however I cannot update this library so I got stuck at this point. I hope you help me, thanks in advance.

I share my pod so they can review it.

```
platform :ios, '10.3'

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

end

def common_pods
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', :git => 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger.git', :branch => '3.0.0'
end


target 'PardosChicken' do
    common_pods
end

target 'PardosChickenTests' do
    pod 'OCMock'
    pod 'Specta'
    pod 'Expecta'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The PR you reference with the fix has not yet been merged.  To point to the PR directly do:

`pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', :git => 'https://github.com/ToshMeston/AFNetworkActivityLogger.git'`

Comment: what mean RP ??

Comment: I try with the example pod but I get this error :  CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "AFNetworking/NSURLSession":
  In Podfile:
    AFNetworkActivityLogger (from https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger.git) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      AFNetworking/NSURLSession (~> 3.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `AFNetworking/NSURLSession (~> 3.0)

Comment: PR not RP, PR is short for Pull Request in github.